# How to use ngx-translate for date DatePipe?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I have an application that it's running in two language ( i can change an choose the language i want bu using i18n) English / French.

At the moment i can get the date only in english even if i select the French Language.

```
   <div class="information">
              {{ information.date | information:'EEEE'}} {{information.date | date:'d'}} {{ information.date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ information.date |
              date:'yyyy'}}
        </div>
```

Is there a way to change the date depending on what language i selected ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class variable as date format like `{{information.date | date:dateFormat}}` and change the date format when the language changes

```
@Component(...)
export class WhateverComponent {

    dateFormat: string;

    dateFormatSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(translateService: TranslateService) {
        const langToDateFormat = lang => {/* map language to date format HERE */}
        this.dateFormat = langToDateFormat(translateService.currentLang);
        this.dateFormatSubscription = translateService.onLangChange().pipe(
            map(langToDateFormat)
        ).subscribe(dateFormat => this.dateFormat = dateFormat);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // don't forget to unsubscribe!!!
        this.dateFormatSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: At the moment i can get the language of my browser, as exemple : Monday 17 August , instead i want to get Lundi 17 Août